# Creating a Slider that changes maximum value if released at maximum

Tags: swift, uislider

Probably a fairly basic error as I am fairly new to swift.  I have an app that creates a slider with min and max values.  These minimum and maximum values will only be a start point, so if someone sets the maximum value I would like to reset the maximum value to something greater.

In xcode I have linked the action to touch up inside.

```
@IBAction func increaseslider(Sender: AnyObject){
if slider.value = slider.maximumvalue{
```

I get errors at this point?  Is there a simpler way to do this?  Or I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code that may be giving you errors:

```
@IBAction func increaseslider(Sender: AnyObject){
if slider.value = slider.maximumvalue{
```

You need to use a double equals sign in the if clause:

```
if slider.value == slider.maximumValue
```

Comment: The brackets are fine, I just didn't include the rest of the code, double equals got it though. Thanks